# Frontend Form for editing entries HTTP Exception

Tags: form, frontend, frontend-form

I took the example form of the craft CMS [Entry Form Documentation page](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/entry-form.html) and tried to use it on a test site.
However i always get a HttpException after submitting the Frontend Form.

[Here's](https://pastebin.com/gnsR7Lb6) the Stack Trace.

And a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3IRn.jpg) of the Error page

Here's the code

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  {{ csrfInput() }}
  {{ actionInput('entries/save-entry') }}
  {{ redirectInput('viewentry/{slug}') }}
  {{ hiddenInput('sectionId', entry.sectionId) }}
  {{ hiddenInput('enabled', '1') }}
  {{ hiddenInput('entryId', entry.id) }}

  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <input id="title" type="text" name="title"
      {%- if entry is defined %} value="{{ entry.title }}"{% endif -%}>

  {% if entry is defined %}
      {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('title')) }}
  {% endif %}

  <input type="submit" value="Publish">
</form>
```

It's a multi-site with 3 languages. So maybe its related to the languages.
But i couldn't find any informations for a frontend form in multi-sites.

Comment: `The user submitting the entry will also need to have the permission necessary to create entries for the section they are posting to.` (https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/entry-form.html), did you already check this?

Comment: @RomainPoirier well i only tested it myself and i am the admin so it should work.

Comment: Did you set the `enableCsrfProtection` setting to `true` in the `config/general.php` file?

Comment: @RomainPoirieryes CsrfProtection is enabled

Comment: Please double check if you are logged in using a user with required permissions while posting the form, because as seen on your screenshot Craft CMS supposes that you made this action as a guest, not a logged in user.

Comment: This is really strange. I was logged in but in chrome this error popped up all the time. It's working in Firefox now. Thanks anyway